# Where does blender store its config files?

Tags: interface

I want to be able to change and store all the settings blender has in a configuration file. Eventually I would like to be able to make self-contained blender plugins that also affect the configuration of blender.

I'm sure there must also exist some settings that are not available in the GUI. For example, I would like to able to configure vim-like keychords for changing the focus of split views, creating them, etc. and in general being able to configure my keys very flexibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re on Windows, check your AppData folder -> Roaming. If on Linux, I might check /use/share but I’d be able to give better blender information in a few days time for that system.

I don’t think there are any configuration settings not covered in the GUI except maybe like GPU drivers or something: Blender is the most configurable interface program I’d ever seen.